# Issue with Database Synchrozation

Tags: sql-server, oracle, replication

I am trying to understand at a conceptual level , how are databases synchronized when they are largely distributed. eg a rail/airline reservation system. Do each of the market leaders have their own proprietary solution to handle this scenario?

Are they all locally present and each transaction is checked against a master copy?

My Scenario a Common Database will have on 11 locations with same schema shall we synch all the databases. This is required for Banking Application.

Comment: This should be closed as too broad.  A great deal depends on the specifics of your requirements and what you're trying to gain from building a distributed application.  I'd start from the premise that you probably don't want a banking application that is distributed across 11 locations.  What happens if one of the 11 branches can't communicate with the central database?  Can I still take all the money out of my account?  Even if I went to a different branch and already withdrew all my money but that transaction hasn't been replicated yet?

Comment: If you disallow local transactions when the local system can't communicate with the central database, then the local database is pointless.  You'd be much better off simply connecting to the local database to run any transactions though maybe you'd want a local read-only cache.

Comment: In light of recent banking systems woes (in UK), I really hope your question is for learning purposes rather than for an actual project at a bank. This sort of task really should be done by experts. However, Oracle have a good primer on concepts here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/ds_concepts.htm . As others have said you must have a thorough grasp of the requirements, and do not underestimate the importance of experience in such architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends - what are the business requirements?  Things like latency, RPO/RTO requirements are additional factors.  Then there is cost aspect.